# Draw Custom Line chart in Android

Tags: android, graph, charts

I want to draw this gradient line chart in Android

Custom line chart

[image: image 1]

Do you know how can I draw this line chart?

Comment: you can use MPAndroidChart library for this

Comment: Can I draw this line chart with gradient MPAndroidChart library?

Comment: then use `LinearGradient` and pass it to `Paint#setShader()` method

Comment: please refer this https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/104

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I'm trying now MpAndroid chart )

Comment: I tried your suggestion but only I drew two colors.How can I draw three colors?  @pskink

Comment: see `LinearGradient` constructors

Comment: Ok thank you @pskink

Comment: I added gradient colors thank you.But I have a problem now.I added 3 limit lines and I want to change chart color when the line chart greater than limit lines.Can I draw this? @pskink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this libraries

-[AchartEngine](https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine)

-[AFreeChart](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/AFreeChart)

-[MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

-[HoloGraphLibrary](https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary)

-[WilliamChart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart)

or Or you can draw yourself using with **View**.class

Answer (score 1):

Try out this library. This you can use as per your need.
[MPAndroid Chart library... It support customisation.](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

Comment: Thank you) I tried and drew my line graph but I have a problem now.I added all line graph in listview but my listview scroll is laggy.I need a suggestion about this

Comment: Instead of using Listview, You can try single linear layout, to which you can add(inflate) your view as you are doing in your bindView method. Since ListView/Recycler view re attaches to a view, it will be laggy. Remove your ListView, and add Single LinearLayout, to which you can inflate the view dynamically, this will removes the laggy. Do not forget to add linear layout inside ScrollView.

Comment: I must to use  Listview beacuse I have some dynamic data and my list is very huge.Like Lazy loading listview

Comment: Yes. You can use linear layout to display dynamic data. You need to dynamically inflate the views and attach it to the linear layout. It won't produce glitch because it won't attaches data to view on a scroll. Make sure, your linear layout should be inside the scroll view.